# :nth-child() selector, multiple nth-child

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I am trying to get click event on table headers and that is easy with jQuery.
I want click event to be active on all headers except first header.

I am escaping first header with :nth-child() property of CSS.

This is how i am doing-

```
$(function(){
$('th:nth-child(2 3 4 5)').click(function(){
$(this).CSS("font-weight","bolder");
});
});
```

I don't get result. Is there any better way i could do it with `:nth-child()` itself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `:not`.

```
$('th:not(:first-child)').click(function(){
```

**OR**

You can use `:gt(0)`

```
$('th:gt(0)').click(function(){
```

**Comment Response**

For odd selector you can use `:odd jQuery` selector.

#### [`Official Document`](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/)

**Example**

```
$('th:not(:odd)').click(function(){
```

Comment: That went well, so if i want to select only `odd` childs, then should id do this- `:nth-child(:odd-child)` or same for even?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$('th:nth-child(n+2)')
```